# Use iprofiler on iOS app

Tags: ios, instruments, profiler

Can I use iprofiler on a iOS application for testing for memory leaks on an app using command line?

Does not matter if it is on the iOS simulator or directly on a iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `iprofiler`, but you can use `instruments` to profile from command line and target different hardware devices.
For instance, if you want to profile for leaks use the "Leaks" template like so:

```
  instruments -t "Leaks" -w your_device_uuid YourAppName.app
```

To see all available templates and device uuid's run:

```
instruments -s
```

More info on this [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/instruments.1.html)